# Set the volume AVAudioPlayer#play(at:time)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer in my app. I have a use case where user specifies the time in future for the sound to play. I can play the sound in background using background modes but I want to control the volume level and set it to max when the sound plays (this is a requirement of the client). After calling `[self.player prepareToPlay];`, I am setting the volume to max by calling `[self.player setVolume: 1.0];` but it seems to have no effect. The sound plays with the device sound level. Any way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it's not possible to change the device volume directly.

Do check Apple's documentation to cater this scenario using MPVolumeView - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview

Comment: I am using MPVoulmeView for another purpose but it does require some action to invoke it. Since nothing is triggered when AVAudioPlayer begins playing a delayed track, I cannot do this. My workaround for this was to use an NSTimer to run in an NSRunLoop which checks currentTime of AVAudioPlayer on tick. Not good approach but I had no other option.